# Substitute all floats for a single character in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with mostly dates as columns.

Ex:

```
  Names 01/04/2020 02/04/2020...
0 Name1        1.0        NaN
1 Name2        2.0        8.0
...
```

I want to substitute all these floats for the character 'P'

Ex:

```
  Names 01/04/2020 02/04/2020...
0 Name1          P        NaN
1 Name2          P          P
...
```

I've tried using iloc, but didn't work:

```
df.iloc[:,1:][df.iloc[:, 1:] >=1] = 'P'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `mask` with `to_numeric`

```
df = df.mask(df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce')).notnull(),'P')
df
Out[19]: 
   Names 01/04/2020 02/04/2020...
0  Name1          P           NaN
1  Name2          P             P
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written on mobile so couldn't test it yet, should work though I believe.

```
import pandas as pd
df.replace(regex=r'([0-9]{1,})?\.[0-9]{1,}$', value='P')
```

Comment: `[0-9]{1,}` can be replaced with `[0-9]+` or `\d+`

Answer (score 1):

if the digits are already string;

```
df.replace(regex=r'\d\.\d+', value='P')
```

If the digits are dtype float;

```
df.astype(str).replace(regex=r'\d\.\d+', value='P')

     Names  01/04/2020 02/04/2020
0  Name1          P           nan
1  Name2          P             P
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to tackle this. Either you can convert all variables to string and use replace function. Or you can try to pick up all float values using a mask and then replace it with value `P`. This would be much more easier to identify.

#### Method 1

```
df.applymask(str).replace("^\s*[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\s*$",'P')
```

#### Method 2

```
def find_float(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False

# Had to fill NA values with 'None' because default NA, numpy.NaN is also a float value.

mask = df.fillna('None').applymap(find_float)

df.where(mask,'P')
```